# Can't connect to MySQL with a new MySQL user

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I work on a personal website. I just put it on the production server. When I am in the development environment I connect to MySQL with root but now I just created a user specific for this website. So I wrote this command line in MySQL:

```
GRANT USAGE ON portefolio.* TO 'userPortefolio'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'myPasswordCrypted'
```

The query is ok, but on my website, when I try to access a page with a query, Symfony gives me that error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'userPortefolio'@'localhost' to database 'portefolio'
```

I tried to restart the server to be sure everything is ok but nothing.
I encrypted the password with the MySQL function

```
password('my password not encrypt')
```

and in Symfony I wrote the password in non-encrypted format. Is that ok?

Answer (score 4):

```
GRANT USAGE ON portefolio.* TO 'userPortefolio'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'myPasswordCrypted'
```

Your password should not be encrypted in this statement. MySQL crypts it automatically.

Comment: if i don't encrypt the password, mysql tell me that:  ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no quirks in connecting etc were made you should do a

```
flush privileges;
```

after running the grant query.

Comment: i don't know about contemporary versions, but back then FLUSH PRIVILEGES was only necessary if you bypassed GRANT/REVOKE and modified the underlying tables directly.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client executes a USE db_name statement. seems like he might not have did a "USE db" after doing the "GRANT query"

Comment: I ever flush privileges and nothing change, and when i connect in command line with the new user with:    mysql -u userPortefolio -p   it's ok but if i "USE portefolio" mysql give me the same error: access denied

Comment: can you do a   SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userPortefolio'@'localhost';   and post it?

Comment: I delete the user and create the same with 127.0.0.1 now but it's the same. Here is the result of the grant: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userPortefolio'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'encrypt password'  But the grant is on all db instead of only portefolio but teh command I type is: GRANT USAGE ON portefolio.* TO 'userPortefolio'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pass';

Comment: Nobody can answer that ?

Comment: @Sniffleh: *If you modify the grant tables indirectly using account-management statements such as GRANT, REVOKE, or SET PASSWORD, the server notices these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again immediately.* and the sentence you quoted is preceded with *privileges for each existing client connection are affected as follows*

Comment: I had this kind of weird issue with permissions not being written, what worked for me was doing a --skip-grant-tables at startup then changing the permissions, didn't go into detail. I'd be happy to talk to you further on this outside of this thread. @justsomebody correct, i was too fast to respond. Also, seems your answer woulde be correct, i'd upvote but not enough rep :)

Answer (score 1):

quoting from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage): *The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “**no privileges**.”*

so everything seems to be working as designed.